# How do I find the shortest sequence of stack moves to get the goal stack?

Tags: python, stack

My task is to write some code that finds the shortest sequence of moves that takes a given starting stack to a given goal stack. I am given an original list of books, portraying how the stack starts out, and a goal list of books, showing the goal order I need them in. The problem lies in that standard sorting algorithms won't work, as the ordering of the books is based off of a person's preference, not of any particular logic.

The system that the question wants you to use is as follows: pull a book out from anywhere in the stack, one at a time, and put it on top of the stack. So if you had books X, Y and Z, you could choose to pull out Y, making the order Y, X, Z.

Initial:

```
'1984 - George Orwell'
'Moby Dick - Herman Melville'
'To Kill A Mockingbird - Harper Lee'
'Atlas Shrugged - Ayn Rand'
'The Black Cat - Edgar Allen Poe'
```

Goal:

```
'Atlas Shrugged - Ayn Rand'
'To Kill A Mockingbird - Harper Lee'
'1984 - George Orwell'
'Moby Dick - Herman Melville'
'The Black Cat - Edgar Allen Poe'
```

This is homework. However, I am not looking for people to do it for me, as that would defeat the purpose of the assignment. I'm just looking for some ideas or tips to get started, as I don't know where to begin.

Note: I was going to tag this as homework however the tag explicitly says not to, so I haven't. If this is wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the main problem is that you can only put onto the top, but you can choose any book. You wanted hints, not the method, so here are some:

1. As you can only put on top always start looking at the bottom as its hardest do reach
2. You obviously never need to pull any book already in the right place
3. You need to pull all books which now are under a book that is above the book in the correct order
4. If you stack books onto the top you should put them there in the correct order
5. To transform A B G F C E D to alphabetical order you would optimally pull E, then F, then G if you always attach to the end.

I hope this got you started and I have not been to explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you make each book its own string variable and then push those variables onto the stack, then proceed with the ordering operations? Or would you use another data structure to collect the books together? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I would save the books as string array/stack and generate a ordered copy before trying to determine the optimal move sequence.

Comment: Oh just remembered you where given the correct order. Sorting otherwise would go by sorted(). So you basically start comparing inital and final lists. Books correctly ordered at the bottom of the stack should e.g. not be touched

Comment: I won't lie, I'm still confused. Do you copy the contents of the stack into a list so that you can iterate over them? My problem is that my stack ADT doesn't allow me to "choose any book," by that I mean I can't access arbitrary elements of the stack because I only have the peek, push, pop, isEmpty and size methods. I hope this makes sense, and sorry for the ignorance. I feel as if this is a stupid question.

Comment: I think you should save the book-stack as Array or List as you need to be able to pull a book from anywhere to be able to solve your assignment. You will stumble across some other false-friends between naming of physical things and computer things.

Comment: Okay. I am using a list. So I'm just pulling from the list and pushing onto the stack, in the correct order? At least, that's where my understanding lies as of now. And thanks again for all your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: You push back to the end of your list. The python list represents you real-world book-stack.

Comment: Do you have an e-mail or skype I can reach you at? If you wouldn't mind further questions, that is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19337/discussion-between-theconstructor-and-trainreq)

Answer (score 0):

A really simple algorithm is to just loop through the stack, each time finding and pulling out the next book that belongs on the bottom. A linear search would be sufficient for a small stack.

In your example, you would pull out `'The Black Cat - Edgar Allen Poe'` on the first iteration, `'Moby Dick - Herman Melville'` on the second, `'1984 - George Orwell'` on the third etc.

This is a O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: I've only a little experience with 'Big O' notation, so can you explain to me why its O(n^2)? And thank you, by the way.

Comment: "find the *shortest sequence of moves*" ... this does not meet the criteria. It generates *a* valid sequence of moves, but not necessarily the shortest one.

Comment: This will not find the fewest moves, but only a possible solution if You look at my A B G F C E D example you would do at least 5 puls (if you ignore A and B) which is more than 3.

Comment: Complete true - it isn't an optimal solution by any stretch of the imagination. It is, however, a starting point that could be used. @trainreq: it makes O(n) comparisons for each of n books, making it O(n^2).